# Decrement GKScore value

Tags: ios, game-center

When I try to store score value less than current value, it doesn't get stored. Any help please?

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"top_matcher"];
scoreReporter.value = currentScore - 10;
[scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"ERROR:%@ %lld %@", error, score, scoreReporter);
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot decrement a score (if your leaderboard is set to be highest first), once you post it, it is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all scores displayed you have to set the score submission type to "most recent score" on iTunes Connect. This will submit all scores to your leaderboard. When retrieving the leaderboard's scores you can sort them by "value descending" youself if you need that functionality.

```
[myLeaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"value" ascending: NO];
    NSArray *sortedScores = [scores sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: @[descriptor]];        
    }];
```

[image]